# Can ffmpeg periodically report statistics on a real-time audio stream (rather than file)?

Tags: ffmpeg

I currently use ffmpeg to capture desktop screen and audio that the computer speakers are playing, something like a screencast. ffmpeg is started by an app that captures its console output, so I can have that app read the output and look for info

I'd like to know if there are a set of switches I can supply to ffmpeg whereby it will periodically output some audio statistics that will directly report, or allow me to infer, that the audio stream has gone silent?

I see some audio statistics switches/filters but the help docs for these seem to imply they will collect their stats over the processing of an entire stream and then report them at the end.. I'd prefer something like "the average audio volume over the past 5 seconds" reported every 5 seconds. I could even deduce from the audio bitrate of the encoder I think, if it's VBR and the rate consistently falls because it's encoding nothing

Comment: Windows Server 2012 R2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there's a silencedetect audio filter:

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#silencedetect

It works just fine on the streaming audio, used like:

```
//some switches have been removed for clarity
ffmpeg -i audio="Line 1 (Virtual Audio Cable)" -af silencedetect=n=-50dB:d=5
```

The d=5 relates to the number of seconds to look back over.  After 5 seconds of silence the standard output/err has something like the following pumped into it:

> [silencedetect @ 0000000002ffe5a0] silence_start: 12.345

After noise returns, something like the following appears in the console

> [silencedetect @ 0000000002ffe5a0] silence_end: 23.456 | silence_duration: 11.111

It's the job of the app reading the output to parse this and do something with it. In my case, as the recording is unattended, I'll signal an alert that the screencast has lost audio